# Filtering by prefix in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have this line:

`let $name := data($item//*[@class='title'])`

Instead of `title` - I want to reference all of the classes that start with `sku`.

A sample class name looks like this:

`sku-RjItMEJEUy1VNUlY`

How would I do this?

Comment: The question "how do I do this" is in this case (as in most situations) about available facilities and their semantics, not about syntax. Correcting the title to be more representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick I think

```
$item//*[starts-with(@class, 'sku')]
```